# How to organize an SQL database to store book text analysis data

Tags: sql, database, performance, data-structures

I have analysed 3 books using the Stanford NLP library. I run my analysis on a page basis, and for every book this is the output I get:

```
// An array of length P, where P is the total number of pages in the book
// so that pageSentiment[0] represents the sentiment of the page 1.
float[] pageSentiment

// An array of length P, where P is the total number of pages in the book
// so that pageWords[0] represents the number of words in the page 1.
int[] pageWords

// An array of length W, where W is the number of unique words in the book
// where, for example, bookWords[0] has the following values
//   word = "then"
//   data[0] = {1, 1, 2} => the word "then" occurs 2 times in page 1 (associated to chapter 1)
//   data[1] = {1, 2, 1} => the word "then" occurs 1 times in page 2 (associated to chapter 1)
//   data[2] = {1, 3, 0} => the word "then" occurs 0 times in page 3 (associated to chapter 1)
//   data[3] = {1, 4, 0} => the word "then" occurs 0 times in page 4 (associated to chapter 1)
//   data[4] = {2, 5, 3} => the word "then" occurs 3 times in page 5 (associated to chapter 2)
//   data[5] = ...
struct WordData { string word; int[,,] data; }
WordData[] bookWords
```

Now... I have to store all those results into an SQL database so that I can access it to plot graphs and statistical tables within a web page. What I'm trying to figure out, now, is the proper way to store all those values in a flexible way so that I can easily send different queries to the database in order to obtain different outputs that follow my current needs. For example... I need to be able to:

- plot an histogram concerning the words count (pageWords) in which
  each column can be either a page or a chapter (in this case I need to
  aggregate page values);
- see the frequency of a word by page or by chapter;
- print global book values for every book;
- ect...

Any suggestion about the structure of my SQL tables, please?

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just 3 tables

```
book
---
book_id
title
...

word
---
word_id
text
...
```

and many-to-many table with results

```
word_2_book
---
word_id
book_id
page_no
chapter_no
word_count
```

Then just

```
select * 
from word_2_book wb
where wb.book_id=? and wb.word_id=?
```

and you can apply any aggregate functions